# org-journal UI behaviour

Tags: org-mode

I'm relatively new to Emacs and org-journal and I'm wondering if I'm doing something wrong or if this is the intended behaviour of org-journal.

When creating a journal entry with C-c C-j the current window is split. Entering data works, but I somehow expected to go back to the window configuration before when finishing the entry like in org-mode (C-c c and C-c C-c). Currently the split remains and when doing another C-c C-j the journal file opens in the other split. So in the end I'm toggling between two splits.

Edit: testing this on Emacs 24.5.1 on Windows, using org-journal 1.9.6

Comment: Mine doesn't split. Do you have anything else installed that manages windows?

Comment: Not sure, this is what I have installed:  
- color-theme-sanityinc-solarized-2.29  
- dash-2.11.0  
- git-commit-2.1.0  
- gnupg  
- magit-2.1.0  
- magit-popup-2.1.0  
- org-journal-1.9.6  
- with-editor-2.1.0  
- org-8.2.10

Comment: Actually, I just updated to the latest org-journal on melpa and it does indeed split the window.

Comment: I added an issue on github: [https://github.com/bastibe/org-journal/issues/52](https://github.com/bastibe/org-journal/issues/52)

Answer (score 1):

I'm the maintainer of org-journal. It is indeed intentional that org-journal opens the journal in a new window.

In the latest version of org-journal, I added an option to customize this behaviour, and optionally open the journal in the current window. Use `(setq org-journal-find-file 'find-file)` to open journal files in the current window.